# Honda Fit 2007 Headlight problem

Tags: honda, headlight

My low and high beam headlight don't turn on. I already checked the bulb and relay. The headlight switch handle is strong and when I pulled to me it doesn't return to his original place alone.

Comment: Welcome to the site. How did you check the bulb and relay if the headlights won't turn on? Am I not understanding what you are saying? Is it only one headlight you are having issue with or both?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if I don't explain well, my principal language is spanish. Both headlight don't turn on. I checked both bulbs with the battery directly and both are good. The relays are already checked too.

Comment: With that information and what you described about the switch handle, it sounds like the switch has gone bad.